# i have a problem adding a linked list into the middle/end accordingly

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

```
/*********************************
* Class: MAGSHIMIM C2            *
* Week:                          *
* Name:                          *
* Credits:                       *
**********************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 20

//Structs
typedef struct personNode
{
    char name[STR_LEN];
    int age;
    struct personNode* next;
} personNode;

//Functions
void insertPersonQueue(personNode** first, personNode* newNode);
void insertAtEnd(personNode** first, personNode* newNode);
personNode* createPerson(char name[], int age);
int listLength(personNode* curr);
void myFgets(char str[], int n);
void printList();

//Global variables
char* friends[3];

int main(void)
{
    personNode* first = NULL;
    int userInput = 0;

    while (userInput != 7)
    {
        printf("\nWelcome to MagshiParty Line Management Software!\nPlease enter your choice from the following options :\n1 - Print line\n2 - Add person to line\n3 - Remove person from line\n4 - VIP guest\n5 - Search in line\n6 - Reverse line\n7 - Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        getchar();

        if (userInput == 2)
        {
            printf("Welcome guest!\n");
            char name[STR_LEN];
            int age, listLenVar;

            printf("Enter name: ");
            myFgets(name, STR_LEN);
            printf("Enter age: ");
            scanf("%d", &age);
            getchar();

            personNode* newPerson = createPerson(name, age);
            insertAtEnd(&first, newPerson);

            printf("Enter names of 3 friends:\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                printf("Friend %d: ", i + 1);
                myFgets(name, STR_LEN);
                friends[i] = (char*)malloc(STR_LEN);
                strcpy(friends[i], name);
            }
            insertPersonQueue(&first, newPerson);
            printList(first);
        }
        else if (userInput == 1)
        {
            int listLenVar = listLength(first);
            printf("%d people in line\n", listLenVar);
            printList(first);
        }
        else if (userInput == 3)
        {
            printf("NOT WRITTEN YET!\n");
        }
        else if (userInput == 4)
        {
            printf("NOT WRITTEN YET!\n");
        }
        else if (userInput == 5)
        {
            printf("NOT WRITTEN YET!\n");
        }
        else if (userInput == 6)
        {
            printf("NOT WRITTEN YET!\n");
        }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/**
Function will add a person to the list
input:
newNode - the new person to add to the list
output:
none
*/
void insertAtEnd(personNode** first, personNode* newNode)
{
    if (!*first)
    {
        *first = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        personNode* p = *first;
        while (p->next)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = newNode;
    }
}

/**
Function will print a list of persons
input: the list (the first person)
output:
none
*/
void printList(personNode* first)
{
    personNode* curr = first;
    while (curr) // when curr == NULL, that is the end of the list, and loop will end (NULL is false)
    {
        printf("Name: %s, Age: %d\n", curr->name, curr->age);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

/**
Function will count the length of the list using recursion
input:
head of the list
output:
none
*/
int listLength(personNode* curr)
{
    int ans = 0;
    if (curr)
    {
        ans = 1 + listLength(curr->next);
    }
    return ans;
}

/**
Function will create a person
input:
person name and his age
output:
the person updated with correct information
*/
personNode* createPerson(char name[], int age)
{
    personNode* newPerson = (personNode*)malloc(sizeof(personNode));

    strncpy(newPerson->name, name, STR_LEN);
    newPerson->age = age;
    newPerson->next = NULL;

    return newPerson;
}

/**
Function will insert a person to the linked lists
if their friend is in the list then it will add that person right before there friend
if he has more than 2 friends that are in the lists it will add him behind the one that is the nearest to the first
input:
double pointer to the first list in the linked lists (the head)
and a pointer to the new list that wanted to be inserted
output:
none
*/
void insertPersonQueue(personNode** first, personNode* newNode)
{
    int fOne = 0, fTwo = 0, fThree = 0, pos = 0;
    if (!*first)
    {
        *first = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        personNode* p = *first;
        personNode* loopP = *first;
        while (p)
        {
            if (strcmp(p->name, friends[0]) == 0)
            {
                fOne = 1;
                fOne += pos;
            }
            else if (strcmp(p->name, friends[1]) == 0)
            {
                fTwo = 1;
                fTwo += pos;
            }
            else if (strcmp(p->name, friends[2]) == 0)
            {
                fThree = 1;
                fThree += pos;
            }
            p = p->next;
            pos++;
        }

        if (fOne >= fTwo && fOne >= fThree && fOne > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fOne - 1; i++)
            {
                loopP = loopP->next;
            }

            printf("new next changed to - %s\nloopP next changed to %s\n", loopP->next->name, newNode->name);
            newNode->next = loopP->next;
            loopP->next = newNode;
            
        }
    }
}

/*
Function will perform the fgets command and also remove the newline
that might be at the end of the string - a known issue with fgets.
input: the buffer to read into, the number of chars to read
*/
void myFgets(char* str, int n)
{
    fgets(str, n, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}
```

i'm having problems in making the function "insertPersonQueue" line 182.

this function recieves a new person list (as a struct) and adds it into the linked lists.

now how this works is that if their friend is in the list then it will add that person right before there friend.

if he has more than 2 friends that are in the lists it will add him behind the one that is the nearest to the first list.

in the printing it's doing it right but it's just printing it forever.

i think i have an idea of why this is happening and it's because in line 213 where i do the changes in the linked list
the list that got moved to the right by 1 the next of it is pointing to the new list that has been added
thats why the program just looping through these two lists.

because the "next" of the new list if pointing to the list that got moved by 1 to the right and that list "next" is pointing to the new list.

that's why in function "printList" in line 127 it's just looping through these 2 lists.

i tried to fix it and it didn't work with me.

in the main function line 44 till line 69 happens the input of the 3 friends, age and name.

output:

---

2

Welcome guest!

Enter name: jake

Enter age: 15

Enter names of 3 friends:

Friend 1: ksi

Friend 2: test

Friend 3: testtt

Name: jake, Age: 15

2
Welcome guest!

Enter name: logan

Enter age: 18

Enter names of 3 friends:

Friend 1: george

Friend 2: testt

Friend 3: tteestrt

Name: jake, Age: 15

Name: logan, Age: 18

2
Welcome guest!

Enter name: moran

Enter age: 16

Enter names of 3 friends:

Friend 1: jake

Friend 2: none

Friend 3: nlolloadsadd

Name: jake, Age: 15

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

LOOPS FOREVER!

---

expected output:

Name: jake, Age: 15

Name: moran, Age: 16

Name: logan, Age: 18

NO LOOPING FOREVER!

Comment: An example will tell much more than 100 lines of textual description. So add the input of the two scenarios. Also add the actual output and the expected output

Comment: sure thing! thanks for letting me know

Comment: Please clarify: 0 friends -> "insert new person at ??", 1 friend -> "insert new person at ",  2 friends -> "insert new person at ??",  3 friends -> "insert new person after the first friend in the list"

Comment: if the person has more than 1 friend that their names are in the linked lists the person won't be placed at the end of the line he will be placed behind the nearest friend to the first linked list (the head of the lists) if the names he puts aren't in the lists then he is placed at the end of the line

Comment: I'll take a look... oh, can friends have the same name... "bill", "joe", "bill"

Comment: hmmm... `loopP->next = newNode` What if loopP is the last node? Then `loopP->next` is NULL Not good...

Comment: yes im ignoring input errors or same names and that stuff

Comment: nope loopP-> will never be null cuz in the for loop i made it loop to the position of that name -1 so it won't be null only if the list has 0 lists in it or 1 not sure tho

Comment: If a person has zero friends where is the code to insert that person?

Comment: i still didn't add it but i already made the function which is called "insertAtEnd" line 104 i will add everything after fixing that bug i have currently

Comment: well, your logic is wrong. You always use `fOne` for insertion but what in the only friend was `friend[2]`

Comment: yes i understand you for now im working on friend[0] when i fix the bug i will add friend[1] and 2 cuz if i fix it it will be easy to add the other ones

Comment: Sorry but your approach is wrong... I'll write answer explaining a solution

Comment: sure thing thank you :)

Comment: `strncpy(newPerson->name, name, STR_LEN);` is wrong. Please lookup strncpy in the manual.

Comment: i see alright i'll make sure i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements (according to discussions in chat) is:

```
0 friends --> Insert new person at the end of the list
1, 2 or 3 friends --> Insert new person after first friend
```

The logic in your `insertPersonQueue` is wrong for several reasons. One example is that it only operates on `friend[0]`. Another is that it doesn't handle the case 0 friends.

In general your implementation is too complex. It can be solved much easier.

Simply iterate (i.e. go through) the list and check whether the current node is a friend of the new person. If the answer is "yes", insert the new person after the current node and return from the function. If you reach the end of the list (i.e. no friend found), insert the new person at the end.

Try this code:

```
void insertPersonQueue(personNode** first, personNode* newNode)
{
    if (*first == NULL)
    {
        // Empty list, i.e. add as head of list
        *first = newNode;
        return;
    }

    personNode* p = *first;
    personNode* prev = NULL;
    while (p)
    {
        if ((strcmp(p->name, friends[0]) == 0) ||
            (strcmp(p->name, friends[1]) == 0) ||
            (strcmp(p->name, friends[2]) == 0))
        {
            // Found the first friend, i.e. insert new person AFTER this person
            newNode->next = p->next;
            p->next = newNode;
            return;
        }
        prev = p;
        p = p->next;
    }

    // No friends found, i.e. add to the end
    prev->next = newNode;    
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would also be good to adapt the question to reflect this new requirements

Comment: @dreamcrash Agree... OP should update the question to make the requirements clear. Currently I'm waiting for OP to approve that this is what OP wants.